# Why doesn't Scala infer type parameters the same way in my abstract class?

Tags: scala, inheritance, abstract-class, type-inference, traits

I've defined 2 traits: `A` and `B`. `B` extends `A`. I've also defined a type parametrized function `addOne` that takes any subtype of `A` as input parameter. I can call this function with an instance of `B` as input since `B` extends `A` (see `success`). However, when I try to do the same thing within the context of an abstract class, this doesn't work anymore. What am I missing?

```
trait A {
  val a: Int
}

trait B extends A {
  val b: Int
}

def addOne[T <: A](t: T): Int = t.a + 1

def success[U <: B](u: U): Int = addOne(u)  // this works!


abstract class C[T <: A, U <: B] {

  def addTwo(t: T): Int = t.a + 2

  def fail(u: U): Int = addTwo(u)  // this doesn't compile

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've solved my problem defining `U` as `U <: T with B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is occurring because, in class C, while you know U is a subtype of B, and T is a subtype of A, you are not guaranteeing that U is a subtype of T.

**EDIT**: I think I've found a way to do this. It uses [generalised type constraints](http://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html):

```
abstract class C[T <: A, U <: B] {

  def addTwo(t: T): Int = t.a + 2

  def fail(u: U)(implicit ev: U <:< T): Int = addTwo(u)  // compiles

}
```

I haven't done a full test of this, though.

Comment: OK. Then, how do I express this relationship between U and T?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to figure a way to do that, but not having much luck short of constraining T to be <: B, or the like, which I'm presuming you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what C is modelling, but I would have said:

```
scala> class C[T <: A, U <: B] { def f(t: T) = t.a ; def g[X <: U with T](x: X) = f(x) }
defined class C
```

That is, you're just trying to say that whatever T and U are, the thing you pass to g is both.

Like the other answer says, where you put the constraints depends on what you're trying to do.